# CSS: Make two floating elements overlap

Tags: html, css

I have two divs within a container. One floats left and one floats right. Both are about 60% as wide as the container and are designed such that they overlap in the middle (right div takes priority).

How do I get them to overlap rather than stack vertically like floating elements usually do? If I absoultely position the right element the containing div doesn't expand to fit the content.

Code (unfortunately I cannot jsfiddle this as their servers are read only atm):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: If I am correct "display:inline" attribute doesn't allow setting dimensions also. This means if you set your display to inline you are not supposed to define any widths and/or heights.
And you float, that inline seems useless for me.
I would use z-index which you can control through javascript on :hovers or click()s (swaps values between the two elements).
How dynamic is your interface?

Comment: The `display:inline` is redundant as any element that is `float`ed is automatically `display:block`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use a negative `margin-right` on the left box so that the right box is allowed to overlap:

```
#left {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right:-104px;
}
```

The 104 pixels is the overlap amount plus 4px for borders.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmUjf/1/).

Comment: So awesome. I've been looking for a solution to overlapping floated columns for a while (for auto-height tabs http://j.mp/1iQ30Fz) This is a perfect solution!

Comment: I dont like this. It seems to be much "custom" case. The problems might happen, if the second element's size is changed from 100px to whatever...

Answer (score 2):

You can only do that with positioning.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#right {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the divs with absolute position and add a positive z-index to the one you want to be in front.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#right {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: In case you didn't know the "px" isn't needed when you define "0px"  you can just use top: 0; save you some characters

Comment: I have done this already but it means the parent container won't expand to fit the content

Comment: You could put the widths of the container and of the divs with percentages instead of fixed values. e.g. container width: 100%, #left width 60% and #right width 60%.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add an extra div in there?

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="left">
        <div id="left-inner">left</div>
    </div> 
    <div id="right">right</div> 
</div> 
<style>
#container { 
    width: 400px; 
} 

#left { 
    float: left;
    width: 0px;
    overflow:visible; 
} 

#left-inner { 
    float: right;
    width: 250px; 
} 

#right { 
    width: 250px; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Adding additional structure to accomplish styling is improper use of HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Bradley A. Tetreault: as a general rule this is right. but reality is worst then this - take IE6-8 as an example and all it's fixes/hacks, which also involves a lot of div.fixer (or div#fixer)

Answer (score 0):

Make container bigger so both fit. Then use position relative and left: -100px or whatever on the one on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent Solution: **http://jsfiddle.net/A9Ap7/237/**

So, dont use:

```
  MARGIN-LEFT:100px...
```

==
 or similar commands.

The problem is that, if the left elements size is changed, if window is resized or etc,,, then it will make you problems!
so, dont use such custom dirty "tricks", but make a normal structure inside html, so they should be naturally ordered.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of allowing two elements which are 60% of the width of the container to overlap.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="left">left</div> 
    <div id="right">right</div> 
</div> 
<style>
#container { 
    width: 400px; 
    background-color: #eee; 
} 

#left { 
    width: 250px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    float: left; 
} 

#right { 
    width: 250px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Comment: they should better to be naturally aligned, instead of tricking.

Answer (score -1):

How about pulling the right div with negative margin. Something like this?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#left {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    top: -100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```