# how to overlap two div in css?

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` likes ,

```
<div class="imageDiv"></div>
<div class="imageDiv"></div>
```

and `css` class ,

```
 .imageDiv
    {
        margin-left: 100px;
        background: #fff;
        display: block;
        width: 345px;
        height: 220px;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    }
```

You can see the result [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aw8RD/) :)

I want to overlap this two `div` likes ,

[image]

Comment: you need to give them different class names and move one. maybe using position relative or css3 translate

Comment: Possible duplicate: **[CSS: Make two floating elements overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227007/css-make-two-floating-elements-overlap)**

Comment: yes , have to make two class as `(.imgDivOne , .imgDivTwo )` :) Can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

add to second div `bottomDiv`

and add this to css.

```
 .bottomDiv{
       position:relative;
       bottom:150px;
       left:150px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aw8RD/1/

Answer (score 7):

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aw8RD/3/) 
 you need to introduce an additiona calss for second div

```
.overlap{
    top: -30px;
position: relative;
left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: +1 , i edited likes >  `top: -100px;position: relative;left: 150px;`

Answer (score 1):

I edited you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw8RD/5/)
you just need to add `z-index` to the front element and position it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JHk4Z/1/) , and if you want to move the overlapped div you set its position to `absolute` then change it's `top` and `left` values

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use just one div and then use pseudo element :: before or ::after and set position of that pseudo element to absolute then set top: 100px and left 100px