# How to overlap two divs with transparency

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two div's that I want to overlap. Div A contains a Google Map and div B is a loading indicator I want to show when some changes are made and the map reloads.

What I want to accomplish is this:

[image: AB]

What I currently get is this (div B not showing at all):

[image: A]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 full-height no-padding">
    <div class="full-height" style="position: relative">
        <div id="B" class="full-height" style="background-color: blue; opacity: 0.5; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99;"></div>
        <div id="A" class="full-height"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few other things such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372000/how-to-overlap-two-div-in-css) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037712/how-to-float-a-div-over-google-maps) but they don't seem to be working, maybe because I'm using Bootstrap and `height: 100%;`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to give `width: 100%` to the div with id="B"