# I need to show a div over another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div and I need to second div to overlap first div.

```
<div id="behind">some text here</div>
<div id="above">some text here</div>
```

I need 2nd div to overlap first.

Comment: Dude!! A Simple google search would help! People here are not for doing your tasks! Please read and show us what you tried b4 asking questions here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Make two floating elements overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227007/css-make-two-floating-elements-overlap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270493/how-would-you-make-two-divs-overlap

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your divs' `position` to anything other than default(which is `static`). So, set it to `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative` and make them overlap each other by adjusting their x,y co-ordinates.

With default `position`, each element takes up its own space on the rendered page and pushes other elements downwards (or horizontally further), so these elements come one after another.

Setting `position` to `absolute` or `fixed` takes the element out of normal flow and the element does not take any ground space on the page now. Now, it can sort of hover above other elements.

```css
#container
{
  position: relative;
}

#container > div
{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#container > div:nth-child(2)
{
  background-color: green;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks sir. Added some explanation.